# Channel-Based Communication and MQTT?

Tags: channel-framework

it seems to me that with the Channel-Based Communication a "subscription" of a private MQTT-Channel should be possible especially Wolfram mentioned that one can commit the MQTT-Path like
ChannelObject["mqtts://...].
My problem: how can I commit "Username" and "Password"?
I further tried "MQTTLink" which is also available in the library, but there is the same problem.
I can subscribe that special, private channel without any problem with any MQTT-Tool like MQTTAnalyzer.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the company Additive and Wolfram:

One can load the (not official supported) package via Get@"MQTTLink`".
To access to a mqtt-broker use

```
myClient=CreateClient["path.to.mqtt-broker:1883", 
 "Username" -> "your-username",
        "Password" -> "your-password"]
```

"path.to.mqtt-broker" means the address, it can be used without "mqtts://"